# writing python list to csv-file

Tags: python-3.x

I have to put this list:

```
result = [(1, 2, 3), (3, 1, 2), (2, 3, 1)]
```

into a csv file which have to look exactly like:
[screenshot of CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRAyW.png)

I have solved it like this:

```
output = open("input.csv","w")

result = [(1, 2, 3), (3, 1, 2), (2, 3, 1)] 

strline = []

for line in result:
    for column in line:
        strline.append(str(column))

output.write(";".join(strline))
print(strline)

output.close()
```

The result is this:

> 1;2;3;3;1;2;2;3;1

but i want this:

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRAyW.png)

So the problem is, that I don't know where I have to put the `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
res = [(1, 2, 3), (3, 1, 2), (2, 3, 1)]
result = ""
for i in res: result += ";".join(list(map(str, i))) + "\n"
print(result)
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it is usually considered good practice to add an explanation of what your code does. This allows for developers who are not knowledgeable in this area to understand what is going on in the code and helps them to learn how to solve the problem by them selves in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use `map()` and `str.join()`:

```
print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: ';'.join(x), result))
```

The `map()` puts semi-colons in between each tuple, then you join it all the lines together using another `join` afterwards.